# How to display month in Tapku calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, tapku

I use Tapku calendar in my iPhone Application,

I have date `2012-11-03 00:00:00 +0000`,

I want to display month of `November` in calendar.

Please suggest me how can i do this?

Comment: please clear that what you want???

Comment: I want to show the month November in tapku calender. Please not the that i have already month and date as i mention in question '2012-11-03 00:00:00 +0000'.

Comment: ok you want to display this declared month when it is appear , right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the following method on your `TKCalendarMonthView`:

```
/** Selects a specific date in the month grid. 
 @param date The date that will be highlighed.
 */
- (void) selectDate:(NSDate*)date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[calendar selectDate:yourDate];
```